# Find and count integers from an array larger than a specific number?

Tags: arrays, visual-studio-2010, for-loop

I have an array that is holding various numbers and what I want to do is find any number that is greater than 200 and count each time a number has been found. I am thinking a For Each loop would be suitable, but am a little lost on the implementation.

```
 Dim intCount As Integer

    For Each Index In _intCholesterolLevel
        If Index > 200 Then

            intCount += 1
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Currently you are checking if the index is >200

Comment: Don't you need assign an initial value to intCount? Like intCount = 0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, but has some confusing parts as mentioned in the comments.  The "For Each" loop returns the value for each element of the array, NOT the array index.  The word "index" refers to the position of the array, so it isn't a good variable name to use.  And you should also initialize intCount to 0.

So again, your code works, but here is a more clear example that produces a correct intCount value of 3

```
Dim intCount As Integer = 0
Dim _intCholesterolLevel() As Integer = {50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350}

For Each cholesterolValue In _intCholesterolLevel
    If cholesterolValue > 200 Then

        intCount += 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! How would I go about collecting the index of those numbers and comparing it another array that holds names? Like "Bob 201". My other array is named _strPatientName

Comment: If you need the array index for the values over 200, then you probably want to switch to using a "For" loop instead of a "For Each".  You can run the loop as For cholesterolIndex = 0 to _intCholesterolLevel.Length - 1 and if _intCholesterolLevel(cholesterolIndex) > 200, then get the name for _strPatientName(cholesterolIndex)

Comment: I have used you example, thanks. However when I try to write the name to a line in the text file, nothing is written. I added "strPatientsName = (_strPatientName(intCholesterolIndex))" and "objWriter.WriteLine(strPatientsName)" in the loop so that the name can be written every time the number is higher then 200. Any ideas?

Comment: Solution, use " objWriter.Close()"